# .zip file password not found (present in .txt file)

Tags: python-2.7

This code is verbatim from a book titled 'Violent Python'. It is meant to be a simple script that iterates through a .txt file and tries each entry as the password to a locked .zip file.

The script runs and no errors are thrown but no output is given until I
 add a count variable that proves each entry is being checked. Although the correct password is in the file the 'if guess:' statement is never run.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
import zipfile

def extractFile(zfile,password):

    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        return password

    except:
        return 

def main():
    count = 0                         #added for debugging 
    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile('secure.zip')
    passFile = open('dictionary.txt')
    for line in passFile.readlines():
        count = count + 1             #added for debugging 
        password = line.strip('\n')
        guess = extractFile(zFile, password)
        print count                   #added for debugging 
        if guess:
            print "[+] Password = " + password + "\n"   
            exit(0)
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That doesn’t seem like a very good book. Any error could be thrown at all and it would be caught with the `except:`.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the `password` before the line `guess = extractFile(zFile, password)` to ensure the password is an exact match as to what is expected?

Comment: Also, as Ryan has touched on, you should also try removing your try/except block and just trying to crack it with the correct password to see what happens. There could be some exception thrown such as file not found

Comment: tried printing `password` before `guess = extractFile(zFile,password)` output was the correct password. Tried removing try/except block, threw a NameError. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zip.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "zip.py", line 14, in main
    guess = extractFile(zFile, password)
  File "zip.py", line 5, in extractFile
    zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
NameError: global name 'zFile' is not defined`

Comment: Man you guys I feel like a complete jerk, I looked at the error and checked to make sure `zFile` was defined properly and looked at every place it was used and caught that in the definition of `extractFile` I forgot to capitalize the F in file. I learned something from what you guys said and it was due to your suggestions I caught the error so thanks a ton! Sorry again for the bonehead move :/